# r devtools test() errors but testthat test_file() works

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I have a function in a package I'm building that assigns a hex-code to the global environment for use by analysts...

```
optiplum<-function(){
  assign(
    x="optiplum",
    value=rgb(red=129,green=61,blue=114, maxColorValue = 255),
    envir=.GlobalEnv)
  }
```

My unit test code is:

```
test_that("optiplum - produces the correct hex code",{
 optiplum()
  expect_true(identical(optiplum,"#813D72"))
})
```

When I run the code manually, there isn't an error:

```
> str(optiplum)
 chr "#813D72"
> str("#813D72")
 chr "#813D72"
> identical("#813D72",optiplum)
[1] TRUE
> expect_true(identical(optiplum,"#813D72"))
```

When I run a test_file() is also does not error

```
> test_file("./tests/testthat/test-optiplum.R")
optiplum : .
```

However, when I run the test as part of my devtools workflow:

```
> test()
Testing optINTERNAL
Loading optINTERNAL
optiplum : 1


1. Failure: optiplum - produces the correct hex code --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
identical(optiplum, "#813D72") isn't true
```

Anyone have any ideas on why this might be occurring and how I can resolve the situation?

Comment: `test()` does it's best to isolate your tests from the global environment. What you're doing is usually a bad idea. Why not just have `optiplum <- function() "#813D72"`?

Comment: Primarily I was (perhaps unfounded) working under the assumption that a variable would be quicker than a function when called many times, but the difference is probably so miniscule I needn't worry.  Will do as you suggest @Hadley, and change the function.  If you post as an answer I'll mark it as such.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment to the global environment is a no-no, see [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) and testthat isolates tests as much as possible (see `test_that()` details).  As a consequence, the `optiplum()` assignment to the global environment would not succeed because the testthat function strictly prohibits such behaviour.

@Hadley rightly points out that the function should just return the string instead of assigning it, particularly since it is just two extra characters for each use.

So not

```
optiplum<-function(){
  assign(
    x="optiplum",
    value=rgb(red=129,green=61,blue=114, maxColorValue = 255),
    envir=.GlobalEnv)
  }
```

but

```
optiplum <- function() rgb(red=102,green=17,blue=109, maxColorValue = 255)
```